# Linear mixed models. how to test if a condition is different from zero.

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have two conditions, A and B (see the figure below).

I want to test if these conditions are different each other,  if condition A is different from 0 and if condition B is different from 0.

I'd like to accomplish this task using a linear mixed model, because I want to consider random effects.

This is my model:

> lm<-lmer(x~conditionr +(1|block) + (1|subj) , data=data, REML = FALSE)

This is the output:

```
            Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -0.08554    0.01745    4.00000  -4.903  0.00781 ** 
   B          0.18395    0.03456 1002.70000   5.323 1.26e-07 ***
```

So, I found a difference between A and B.  A (Intercept) is different from 0.

However, I don't know:
 1) how to test if B is different from zero. 
 2) is it possible that the df of intercept is 4? it sounds a bit strange for me..

Thanks in advance
BR

[image]

Comment: In this case you can suppress the intercept: `x ~ 0 + conditionr +(1|block) + (1|subj)` . But the `multcomp` package allows for more complex tests: `library(multcomp) ; summary(glht(m, matrix(c(1, 1), 1)))`

Comment: Very thanks!  Could a contrast matrix like this work?  K <- rbind(c( 1,  0) ,
            c( 0,  1),  
            c( 1, -1) 
 )

Comment: Yes, but I think the final row of K should be c(1,1) if you want to test if B=0 for the model with the intercept included (as in your question). Otherwise, c(1,-1) can be used for the difference for the model with intercept suppressed

Comment: of interest https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204741/which-multiple-comparison-method-to-use-for-a-lmer-model-lsmeans-or-glht